# I can't understand what this statement means. [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSince1970] < [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - 60

Tags: iphone, nsdate

I can't understand what this statement means.

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *) manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if ([newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSince1970] < [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - 60)
    return;
}
```

timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate returns the interval between the receiver and the first instant of 1 January 2001, GMT.

How do we compare 1970 and 2001 ?

Comment: Where is this code? Are you sure it's not just a typo/auto completion bug? If I were to replace timeIntervalSince1970 with timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate, then the code makes sense: it doesn't treat new locations older than 60 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat it as what it, most likely, is. A typo.

Books have typos too, and all those books that are written in a hurry to get them out on time (ie everything iOS related) have a lot of them.

That's why you should never copy and paste code without understanding it.

replace it with

```
if ([newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSince1970] < [NSDate timeIntervalSince1970] - 60)
```

or

```
if ([newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] < [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - 60)
```

your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Without having the whole context, it's difficult to tell. But the result is true if the location's timestamp is closer to the beginning of 1970 than now to the beginning of 2001 (-60).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not iPhone dev but you might be able to try comparing time with millisecond based. (if Java, there is Calendar object that would do most of date comparison) not sure for Objective c though.